# jQuery close current submenu after mouseout() menu or submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working with this [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m956z0t/).
My solution works but I need something which closes submenu after `mouseout()` currently it opens submenu item or when mouseout() submenu2 because when I'm out of submenu2 or I'm at next item I don't want to see previous submenu2.

Simply something like this:

```
if ($.submenu li.item152 == mouseout() || $.submenu2'.eq(0) == mouseout()){
 $('.submenu2').eq(0).slideUp(600);}
```

How can i do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .Hide all with `mouseleave`

```js
$('.submenu li.item152').hover(function() {
$('.submenu2').eq(0).slideDown(600);
$('.submenu2').eq(1).slideUp(600);
}); 

$('.submenu li.item153').hover(function() {
$('.submenu2').eq(1).slideDown(600);
$('.submenu2').eq(0).slideUp(600);
}); 

$('.submenu2').mouseleave(function(){
$('.submenu2').slideUp(600);
});
```

```css
.submenu2{
  display: none;
}

.submenu li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="submenu">
<li class="item152">
Item 152
</li>
<li class="item153">
Item 153
</li>
</div>

<div class="submenu2">
<li>submenu for item 152</li>
<li>submenu for item 152</li>
<li>submenu for item 152</li>
</div>
<div class="submenu2">
<li>submenu for item 153</li>
<li>submenu for item 153</li>
<li>submenu for item 153</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to fix  Your HTML **li** must be under **ul** tag then use hover function for toggle submenu:

```js
$(".menu li").hover(
  function() {
    $('.submenu.'+ $(this).attr('class')).slideDown(600);
  },
  function() {
     $('.submenu.'+ $(this).attr('class')).slideUp(600);
  }
);
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item152">
    Item 152
  </li>
  <li class="item153">
    Item 153
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="submenu item152">
  <li>submenu for item 152</li>
  <li>submenu for item 152</li>
  <li>submenu for item 152</li>
</ul>
<ul class="submenu item153">
  <li>submenu for item 153</li>
  <li>submenu for item 153</li>
  <li>submenu for item 153</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, pure css solution:

```css
ul.submenu li{
  position:relative
}

.submenu2{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0px
}


ul.submenu li:hover ul.submenu2{
  display: block;
  
}

ul.submenu2 li:hover{
  display: block;
  top:10px
}

.submenu ul li{
  
  padding-right: 10px;
}


.submenu li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="submenu">
<li class="item152">
Item 152
<ul class="submenu2">
<li>submenu for item 152</li>
<li>submenu for item 152</li>
<li>submenu for item 152</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item153">
Item 153
<ul class="submenu2">
<li>submenu for item 153</li>
<li>submenu for item 153</li>
<li>submenu for item 153</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```